# Why would Google Analytics's funnel visualization have the tracked funnel step as an exit page?

Tags: google-analytics

I am doing some UX research and while looking at the funnel visualization in GA each step has a list of exit page URLs. For most of the steps, the actual URL of the step is the top URL in the exit page list.

Is the page being reloaded? What is happening here? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Sample screen shot

[image screen shot](https://ibb.co/WVR8xpK)

Answer (score 0):

Funnel Visualization report has its own logic.

If the user went back to the previous step or refreshed the page, the Funnel Visualization report will show it as an exit.

Find more information on how this funnel woks here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en

Comment: This report is the difference between Funnel Visualization vs. Goal Flow which does not answer the question above. Thank you though for your feedback.

Comment: The link explains the difference between the two funnels but provides information on how funnel visualization works. Consequently I believe it also contains the explanation to your question. However, considering that this funnel can be misleading for various reasons I suggest you to insert some more information and some screenhot to your question.

Comment: I added a screenshot for anyone that needs a visual

Comment: If the user went back to the previous step or refreshed the page, the Funnel Visualization report will show it as an exit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a high chance your cart page includes several other screeens (address, shipping, payment) probably loads the page again and again. You may want to [virtually track them](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages#modifying_page_urls).